# How to format numbers within knitr::kable function

Tags: r, knitr, kable

Is there a way to format numbers in the `kable` function without converting the data in the source object to a formatted string?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

test.data <- data.frame(merchant = c("merchant 1",
                                     "merchant 2",
                                     "merchant 3",
                                     "merchant 4",
                                     "merchant 5"), 
                        amount = c(3158.01,
                                   2341.67,
                                   1873.24,
                                   1578.15,
                                   1273.19))

test.data %>%
  kable() %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
```

What do I need to pass to the `kable` function to style the numbers as currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the result I ended up with, using `curency` in the `formattable` package when passing the data frame to `kable` (there may be a better way, I'm only 6-months into using R):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
library(formattable)

test.data <- data.frame(merchant = c("merchant 1",
                                     "merchant 2",
                                     "merchant 3",
                                     "merchant 4",
                                     "merchant 5"), 
                        amount = c(3158.01,
                                   2341.67,
                                   1873.24,
                                   1578.15,
                                   1273.19))
data.frame(test.data$merchant, currency(test.data$amount)) %>%
  kable(col.names = c("Merchant", "Amount Spent")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = FALSE)
```